# cause for high Interrupts and context switches

Tags: central-processing-unit, cpu-usage, interrupts, irq, context-switch

I have a quad core and I have spotted on munin (monitoring interrupts and context switches), that my interrupts and context switches spiked to 25k a second while the average was 250 for some time.

No idea what happened, and also no idea what does it mean, except from the fact that it is an anomaly according to my monitoring tools.

This happened in one of my openVZ virtual container.

Note: At the same time, load spiked to 2.5 and CPU usage was at the same point 110% system, 15% user and 100% IOwait.

I have attached the output for /proc/interrupts on the host machine.

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:   48039108   56660082   56431151   51696624    IO-APIC-edge  timer
  1:          0          3          0          0    IO-APIC-edge  i8042
  4:          4          4          1          3    IO-APIC-edge  serial
  8:          1          0          0          0    IO-APIC-edge  rtc
  9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-level  acpi
 12:          4          0          0          0    IO-APIC-edge  i8042
 50:         15         16         16         16   IO-APIC-level  ata_piix
 66:      11113          0          0   56276172         PCI-MSI  eth0
169:   12839820    4849263       1080       1167   IO-APIC-level  ioc0
225:          6          7          5          5   IO-APIC-level  ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb2, uhci_hcd:usb4
233:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-level  uhci_hcd:usb3
NMI:      17173      16340      16694      17306 
LOC:  214221117  214220936  214196385  214196306 
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be a multi-threaded application doing a lot of locking. Everytime it locks, the CPU will pre-empt its quantum and allows another thread to have a go. You can write M/T apps that spend all their time sloshing between threads, none of which end up doing any useful work, and because they are causing all those context-switches, the CPU spends more time switching threads than the threads themselves get to do work.

See if there's any spikes in CPU usage for an app during these spikes.

Comment: To be pedantic, entering the kernel is only needed when the lock is contended, or when waking up waiting tasks. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex

Comment: yes, of course, I meant every time it enters a wait state - ie locked on a busy/held resource.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a numerical artifact that the monitoring system produced, caused by a very short time slice. Maybe it's just a sampling effect that you're seeing here.

Answer (score -3):

Might it be that the linux kernel timer (**`CONFIG_HZ`**) is set to trigger regularly, at 250Hz? Check the kernel config file. There are other frequencies to choose from.

Comment: That still doesn't explain the sudden spike, it was on an average of 250 and then suddenly it jumped to 30k/sec !